# Docker build issues with python and data science packages

Tags: docker, dockerfile, alpine-linux

Relatively new to docker (building and creating) and I am running into an issue when I attempt to build a docker image with data science packages.  The process seems to error out on python selection but I'm not sure why.  I have my docker file (Dockerfile) in the directory root where I am attempting to build.  It makes it through the build process to some degree and then fails:

```
------                                                                          
 > [3/3] RUN apk add --no-cache --virtual build-dependencies python --update py-pip     && apk add --virtual build-runtime     build-base python-dev openblas-dev freetype-dev pkgconfig gfortran     && ln -s /usr/include/locale.h /usr/include/xlocale.h     && pip install --upgrade pip     && pip install --no-cache-dir     numpy     matplotlib     scipy     scikit-learn     pandas     nltk     wordcloud      && apk del build-runtime     && apk add --no-cache --virtual build-dependencies     dumb-init     musl     libc6-compat     linux-headers     build-base     bash     git     ca-certificates     freetype     libgfortran     libgcc     libstdc++     openblas     tcl     tk     libssl1.0      && rm -rf /var/cache/apk/*:
#6 0.159 fetch https://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.15/main/aarch64/APKINDEX.tar.gz
#6 0.742 fetch https://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.15/community/aarch64/APKINDEX.tar.gz
#6 1.008 ERROR: unable to select packages:
#6 1.021   python (no such package):
#6 1.021     required by: build-dependencies-20220407.173111[python]
------
executor failed running [/bin/sh -c apk add --no-cache --virtual build-dependencies python --update py-pip     && apk add --virtual build-runtime     build-base python-dev openblas-dev freetype-dev pkgconfig gfortran     && ln -s /usr/include/locale.h /usr/include/xlocale.h     && pip install --upgrade pip     && pip install --no-cache-dir $PYTHON_PACKAGES     && apk del build-runtime     && apk add --no-cache --virtual build-dependencies $PACKAGES     && rm -rf /var/cache/apk/*]: exit code: 2
(base) tdentry@VONFVFGG5STQ05N kaggle_assignment % docker build -t tdentryr/python-datascience:3.9 -f Dockerfile .
```

Any ideas on why this might be failing?

Comment: `python` is not a valid Alpine package since the version 3.5. Try to install the `python3` package instead.

Comment: Thank you B.enoit.Be - where do you define in the Dockerfile where python3 is installed?  Would it be in this portion?  

RUN apk add --no-cache --virtual build-dependencies python --update py-pip \
    && apk add --virtual build-runtime \
    build-base python-dev openblas-dev freetype-dev pkgconfig gfortran \
    && ln -s /usr/include/locale.h /usr/include/xlocale.h \
    RUN apk add --no-cache --virtual build-dependencies python --update py-pip \
    && apk add --virtual build-runtime \
    (breaking this into two messages)

Comment: && apk add --no-cache --virtual build-dependencies $PACKAGES \
    && rm -rf /var/cache/apk/*

CMD ["python3"] -- this is where I changed to python3

Comment: You are doing `RUN apk add --no-cache --virtual build-dependencies python` do `RUN apk add --no-cache --virtual build-dependencies python3` instead.

Comment: Hard to tell without your Dockerfile, to be honest.

Comment: @β.εηοιτ.βε.. The file is too long for StackOverflow's comments sections, so I'm breaking it up and excluding standard info: 
`ENV PYTHON_PACKAGES="\
    numpy \
    matplotlib \
    scipy \
    scikit-learn \
    pandas \
    nltk \
    wordcloud \ 
" `

Comment: `RUN apk add --no-cache --virtual build-dependencies python3 --update py-pip \
    && apk add --virtual build-runtime \
    build-base python-dev openblas-dev freetype-dev pkgconfig gfortran \
    && ln -s /usr/include/locale.h /usr/include/xlocale.h \
    && pip install --upgrade pip \
    && pip install --no-cache-dir $PYTHON_PACKAGES \
    && apk del build-runtime \
    && apk add --no-cache --virtual build-dependencies $PACKAGES \
    && rm -rf /var/cache/apk/*

CMD ["python"] `

Comment: [edit] your question, do not put that in a comment.

Comment: @β.εηοιτ.βε thank you so much.  I figured out the problem.  There was a line where python was incorrectly typed (instead of python3)
` RUN apk add --no-cache --virtual build-dependencies python3 --update py-pip \
    && apk add --virtual build-runtime \
    build-base python3-dev openblas-dev freetype-dev pkgconfig gfortran \ `

I had incorrectly typed 'python' in the virtual build dependencies line.

Answer (score 0):

1. It would nice if posted a valid Dockerfile
2. The error is: **python (no such package)**, I would try to identify which package is missing using a process of elimination and then figure out why it's missing.

Comment: Thank you for responding, Frank.  The file is too long for StackOverflow's comments sections, so I'm breaking it up and excluding standard info:
```
# SOFTWARE PACKAGES
#   * musl: standard C library
#   * lib6-compat: compatibility libraries for glibc
#   * linux-headers: commonly needed, and an unusual package name from Alpine.
#   * build-base: used so we include the basic development packages (gcc)
#   * bash: so we can access /bin/bash
#   * git: to ease up clones of repos
```

Comment: ENV PYTHON_PACKAGES="\
    numpy \
    matplotlib \
    scipy \
    scikit-learn \
    pandas \
    nltk \
    wordcloud \ 
"

Comment: RUN apk add --no-cache --virtual build-dependencies python --update py-pip \
    && apk add --virtual build-runtime \
    build-base python-dev openblas-dev freetype-dev pkgconfig gfortran \
    && ln -s /usr/include/locale.h /usr/include/xlocale.h \
    && pip install --upgrade pip \
    && pip install --no-cache-dir $PYTHON_PACKAGES \
    && apk del build-runtime \
    && apk add --no-cache --virtual build-dependencies $PACKAGES \
    && rm -rf /var/cache/apk/*

CMD ["python"]

Comment: Please create https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example in order to get help. Thx